# Add more color palettes to iris color picker, without overwriting current palette?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using iris color picker with a few preset color palettes. Now I want to add more colors, however I don't want to touch the previous code. I need a solution to extend the color palettes without touching the original code.

The problem I have, is that if I use the palette parameter again, it simply overwrites the previous selected palettes.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#color-picker').iris({
        hide: false,
         palettes: ['#125', '#459', '#78b'],
    });

     $('#color-picker').iris({
         palettes: ['#000', '#000', '#000'],
    });
});
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ctrmsyx/

I also can't just add the previous color palettes, since there are dozens of different color pickers across the site, each with their own color palettes.

The easiest solution would be to somehow have a function to extend the palettes, rather than overwriting them.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working for you because you are overriding the palette. In order to **append** to the pre-existing palette of an Iris instance, you will have to retrieve the palette array first, append/concat to it, and then update the palette variable.

From the Iris documentation, you can [retrieve the palette information using the options syntax](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/#option), i.e.:

```
var palette = $('#color-picker').iris('option', 'palettes');
```

Once you have retrieved the palette, you can perform `array.concat()` to add your new palette to it, i.e.:

```
$('#color-picker').iris('option', 'palettes', palette.concat(['#fff', '#ddd', '#bbb', '#999', '#777', '#555', '#333', '#111']));
```

Here is a proof-of-concept, functional example based on your fiddle:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#color-picker').iris({
    hide: false,
    palettes: ['#125', '#459', '#78b'],
  });

  var palette = $('#color-picker').iris('option', 'palettes');

  // Let's say we want to add three grey scale colors on top of your pre-existing palette
  $('#color-picker').iris('option', 'palettes', palette.concat(['#fff', '#ddd', '#bbb', '#999', '#777', '#555', '#333', '#111']));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/iris.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="color-picker" value="#bada55" />
```

I have also forked/updated your fiddle, you can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/8ctrmsyx/1/